# Do skills bought in Ubiquity character creation start at level 1 or level 0?

Tags: skills, ubiquity

During character creation, it says that skills are bought on a 1 for 1 basis and that you begin the game with 4 Zero-level skills that costs 1/2 pt to raise to level 1.

Our Game Master is taking this to mean that you need to spend 1 point to get a skill to level 0 because the rules include 0 level skills on their chart. So in order to get a skill at level 5 it would cost 6 points (or 5-1/2 for a zero level skill).

I think that the 0 level skills rules only apply to the 4 that you start the game with.

What is the actual rule?

Answer (score 10):

### Buying Skills in Ubiquity Character Generation:

In Ubiquity games which include Zero-level skills, a number of skills are assigned at that zero-level to ensure that the characters have those skills at least at a Rating which obviates the 'untrained skill-use penalty'. These might relate to occupation or to culture, but are considered ubiquitous to the sort of character the players will be using.

These assigned zero-level skills can be raised in character generation or afterward.

Additional zero-level skills can be purchased in character generation if a player wishes to start with those skills at zero-level, otherwise all new skill purchases in character generation start at level one and cost 1 point for each level purchased. These levels add to the associated attribute to determine the final skill Rating.

The cost to raise a skill from zero-level to level one is 1/2 of a point. It is most convenient to take care of this in pairs. If this is done, the cost to raise a skill from level one to level two is 1 point. All skills in character generation cost 1 of your 15 starting XP for 1 level. Most Ubiquity games have a cap of level 5 in character generation.

It is permissible to add additional zero-level skills in character creation and they cost 1/2 of a point to buy.

There is no real reason to purchase additional zero-level skills if the intent is to raise them during character creation. New skills purchased in character creation or in development after play start at level one unless you specifically pay the half-cost to start with it at zero-level.

> To start with level five in diplomacy during character generation will
>   cost 5 of your starting XP. If it is your intention to start with this
>   skill at level 5, then there is no need to consider the zero-level as
>   that cost is already a part of reaching level one.

### Buying New Skills in Ubiquity with Earned XP

Characters improved in play will be able to acquire new skills for a cost of 2 XP (New level x 2). The new skill starts at Level 1 and adds that value to the associated Attribute to determine the skill's Rating. (Charisma 3 + Diplomacy 1 for a Diplomacy Rating of 4). As noted in the Experience Points section in the General Rules chapter of whatever Ubiquity game you play, a skill can only be improved one level at a time when developing via earned experience. (They can be increased to a specific level when in character generation).

Zero-level skills are an optional component of some games and a standard part of others, and not included in still others, depending on several factors (see below).

Generally speaking, zero-level skills are an aspect of character creation rather than improvement in play, but in the area of zero-level Resources, there are guidelines that can be used to allow for the acquisition of zero-level skills if that is desired and sensible in the context of play.

- Zero-Level skills will cost 1 point (per the rules) to acquire in play (1 XP to raise to 1 later)
- Zero-Level Resources will cost 7 points to acquire in play (8 XP to raise to 1 later)

> If a Zero-Level Skill is later raised to 1, the normal costs apply to
>   raise it to Level 2 (4 points). To go from 2 to 3 costs 6 points, and so
>   on. The rule for raising Skill level is New Level x 2. Likewise, a Zero-level Resource will require the normal XP costs one it has been raised to level 1. 15XP per level.

### Experience Points: Starting

The XP costs for building a character are not the same as those for developing a character. The cost to buy a skill point in character creation is only 1 of your starting XP. They are higher when developing the character in play.

At character creation in some Ubiquity games, 4 zero-level skills might be assigned, and depending on the game, 2 zero-level Resources might be assigned as well.

These can be raised to Level one for 1/2 the normal cost.

To purchase a new skill in character generation at zero-level costs 1/2 a point (so two zero-level skills need to be purchased or 1/2 a point will be wasted).

### Experience Points: Development

To raise a pre-existing zero-level Skill to Level One after play has begun, the cost is noted in the rules as being 1 in the 'Zero-Level Skills section of the game you are using or drawing from. To raise the Skill later to Level Two has the normal cost (New level x2; raising a 1 to a 2 costs 4 points).

To purchase a Zero-level Skill in play, if this is allowed in the game, can be assumed to cost 1/2 the normal requirement as this 1/2 cost remains consistent in each case. A new skill earned in play costs 2 points, therefore a new zero-level skill earned in play would cost 1 point.

**Zero-level Resources**
Buying a new Resource at zero-level likewise costs 1/2 its normal cost of 15 XP. This could be done with your 15 bonus XP in character creation, or later with earned XP from play.

The core rules place the split at 7 points to purchase the zero-level, and 8 points to raise it to 1 later. To buy subsequent levels costs 15 XP per level.

### Background: Generic System?

Ubiquity, although very flexible, is not (yet) a generic system. As a result, each line has rules specific to to that line which reinforce the specific nature of the setting, genre, etc. In most cases those rules can be transferred to any of the other games, but in some - most notably magic - there are many options to choose from and these choices are not compatible.

Zero-level skills are a part of the original Ubiquity game (*Hollow Earth Expedition*) but did not appear in the core book (*Secrets of the Surface World* has the introductory section on these rules). Games which feature zero-level skills prominently as a part of the core rule set are *All for One: Regime Diabolique* and *Leagues of Adventure*.

Comment: Ruuuuuneslinger been a while son!  Welcome back.

Comment: I have missed you, too~

Comment: So happy to have you back.  .

Comment: Thanks, Runeslinger, for answering my question - we actually decided to go with this system after watching several of your videos.

Comment: However, my question was regarding the 15 points spent for skills **during** character creation (I have no idea where that heading came from).  Does it cost 2 starting skill points to bring a non-Zero-level skill to 1

Comment: I will update the answer~

Comment: Seems like your argument is "you can buy in at level 0 or at level 1." Is this supported anywhere? Eg, what under this interpretation stops me from buying a new skill at level 3 instead?

Comment: My answer already informs you that this is possible. In character creation, levels are purchased on a 1 level for 1 point basis, allowing you to have any number of levels between 1 and the typical cap of 5 in whatever skill you please. After character creation, there is a cap of a 1 level per opportunity to increase level with experience.